# Rotate a Vector3 around Z axis

Tags: math, vector, rotation

I have a Vector3, and I need to rotate it around the Z axis because I need the new X and Y coordinates.

I am currently trying to multiply the vector with a matrix , but am not sure this is the proper way to do it.

How do I do this?

Comment: How about showing us what you tried?

Comment: Hint: Rotating (x,y,z) around the z-axis does not change z. You can just rotate (x,y) in the plane.

Comment: I think you need to do some reading up.  Rotation matrices are described in detail at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix and use of quaternions to do the same thing is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation.  If you have some questions about what's there, you can post another question here or over on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a` being the rotation angle, the rotation matrix would be this:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)     0
sin(a)   cos(a)     0
 0        0         1
```

Just multiply your vector by that matrix.